# spring jndi and jta with weblogic

Tags: spring, weblogic, jndi, entitymanager, jta

I am getting confused about the way to configure spring's JTA JNDI with weblogic:

as I understood, `<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="jdbc/oracledb" />`

serves to bind the datasource with the name  (already created in the weblogic server) in an **EntityManagerFactory**.
and then to allow spring detecte the JPA annotations and injects the appropriate values in the DAO we define the  bean

```
<bean       
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

and for the jndi:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="jdbc/oracledb" />
```

to activate spring's jta:

```
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

my persistence.xml file is:

```
   <persistence-unit name="ebankingUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/oracledb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.datamodel.Product</class>
```

the error I'm getting is that the entity Manager is **NULL** inside the DAO,

Is there any problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup `<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="jdbc/oracledb" />` is almost certainly for the DataSource, not the entityManagerFactory. Your configuration would probably need to be

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/oracledb" />

<bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Comment: thanks this solved my problem, Thank you spo much. I was thinking to in the same way, I noticed that I was missing up with classes and then start defining the classes returned by each xml declaration. I am getting a new error, but this time it is versions problem: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-datasource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

Comment: Hi, one more question if you don't mind. <jee:jndi retreives a datasource from the jndi name in the JEE server right? but in the persistence.xml we declare a <jta-data-source> witch binds the datasource to entitymanagerFactory, this sames as a duplication of datasource reference

Comment: This seems like a valid question, however I don't have an informed answer for you...